# how to publish mvc3 application on build server using msbuild scripts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, msbuild

I am trying to publish my mvc3 application on build server. I have installed below listed item on server

1. NetFramework 4
2. Mvc3
3. microsoft sdk

but when i am trying to run msbuild scripts then i am getting below message

**The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

please let me know what i have missed or should i need to configure something?

Answer (score 0):

In the **Web.config** section:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation>
        <assemblies>
```

add the following line:

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Comment: i got the solution. mvc dll of my application was pointing to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 2 on the time of buid and in build server i have only C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3.so i have added mvc dll in my project which is reside in ASP.NET MVC 3 folder.at the end my problem is resolved..:)